# OpenCV-Python: cv2.VideoCapture(0).grab and cv2.VideoCapture(0).read hangs

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I am using Python 2.7 with OpenCV 3.0 Beta and my webcam is Logitech webcam pro 9000.

Cheese application is running fine indicating no issue with the webcam driver.

On calling `cv2.VideoCapture(0).read()` (or `grab()`), I get the error 'select timeout' after about 10 seconds.

I googled this extensively and found the following solution:

`sudo rmmod uvcvideo`

`sudo modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80`

Now the API `cv2.VideoCapture(0).read()` (or `grab()`) just hangs.

Comment: Tried with 2.4.0 and 2.4.10 but still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Wouldn't this call the constructor for `VideoCapture` every time you write this statement? It's probably more than just a convenience to write `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and `cap.read()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cv` instead of `cv2`

```
import numpy
import cv2.cv as cv
import cv2
capture = cv.CreateCameraCapture(-1)
while True:

    frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    aframe = numpy.asarray(frame[:,:])
    cv2.imshow("w1", aframe)
    c = cv.WaitKey(5)
    if c == 110: #to quit, the 'n' key is pressed
        exit()
```

Comment: Now it hangs on `frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)`